# What would be the C# equivalent of the following struct defined in C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll, struct

I have the following structs defined in C++ used in one of my project which are to be re-used for another project in C# script of Unity engine. I wish to use these struct types as argument types between the C# script and C functions in a dll but I do not know how to convert them into C# declaration.

Here are the struct definitions:

```
struct SMove
{
    std::string m_MotionID;
    std::string m_AnimSrc;
    float           m_StartFrame;
    float           m_EndFrame;

// features

enum XFEATURE
{
    XFEATURE_NONE = 0,

    // Insert new features
    XFEATURE_ENERGY,            
    XFEATURE_POWERLEVEL,            

};

float           m_Intensity;
};

struct SElement
{
    float           m_Start;
    float           m_End;
};
typedef std::vector<SElement> TElements;

struct SGroup
{
    float           m_Start;
    float           m_End;
    long            m_Level;

    TElements       m_Elements;
};
typedef std::vector<SGroup> TGroups;

struct SDivision
{
    std::string m_PlayerID;
    std::string m_DivisionID;
    float           m_Start;
    float           m_End;

    TGroups     m_Groups;

    // features
    float           m_Intensity;

};
typedef std::vector<SDivision> TDivisions;

typedef std::vector<long*>      TScript;

struct SScriptList
{
    TScript* m_Seg[9][4][2];
};
```

I have just started learning C# and I know it can only interop with C so all std::string and std::vector has to be somehow replace with something recognised in both C and C#. I know std::string can be replaced with const char* but how do I go about converting the rest? I have googled many sites but couldn't find any examples similar to mine. How do I declare arrays of struct inside another struct in C# and its C equivalent like in SDivision and SGroup?

**Update:**

I have converted some of the structs to C as follows:

```
struct SElement
{
    float           m_Start;
    float           m_End;
};

struct SGroup
{
    float           m_Start;
    float           m_End;
    long            m_Level;

    //Array of Elements     
    SElement*       m_pElements;
    int             m_numElements;
};

struct SDivision    {
    const char*     m_PlayerID;
    const char*     m_DivisionID;
    float           m_Start;
    float           m_End;

    //Array of Groups
    SGroup*     m_pGroups;
    int             m_numGroups;

    float           m_Intensity;
};
```

What would the C# equivalent be?

Comment: What do you want? Do you want the C# equivalent of the structs, i.e. valid C# code? Or do you want to have valid C or C++ code that can be used in C# with P/Invoke. This are two completely different things!

Comment: I want to use these structs as arguments for functions imported from a C DLL plugin for Unity C# scripts. I supposed that means I would need valid C# code in the script and equivalent C struct in the DLL project but I am not too sure though...

Comment: you use STL containers in your struct, there is no easy way to marshal them to C# code. You might want to replace them with c arrays. Other then that everything will be easy.

Comment: Yes I know but if I replace std::vector with a pointer to that object, what would the C# equivalent be? I would like to maintain the composition relationship of SDivision has an array of SGroup which has an array of SElement and also have dynamic array sizes.

Comment: You should take a look at http://pinvoke.net/. They'll give you a lot of examples on how to access most of the Win32-API structures. Maybe there you'll find an equivalent example to your problem, so that you can adapt it to your exact wishes.

Comment: `enum XFEATURE` has no field name. What is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 0):

Best course of action here is to have C++/CLI bridge DLL. C++/CLI bridge should be built with the same version of Visual Studio in which original DLL is built. The build result is regular .NET library.